# Need total count of unqiue VM's for particular Cluster using dynamic range in excel

Tags: excel

[image: Sheet1]

[image: Sheet2]

[image: Sheet3]

Hello All,

I'm working on data where I need details of Unqiue total VM used by particular cluster. I've attached Sheet1 where Cluster are A,B,C in Column B & VM's in Column A.

I've attached Sheet 2 where I've Column A shows Cluster A,B & C & Column B "Total Unique VM" I've used below formula using dynamic range :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((Sheet1!B:B=A2))/COUNTIFS(Sheet1!B:B, Sheet1!B:B&"",Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!A:A&""))
```

The formula reflects only 0 for all cluster's A, B & C.

In Sheet2 Column D shows actual result is needed.

More complicated situation where Cluster Name is not known, & we have the VM's available. So how to get the VM's (sum / count) where Cluster is not known?

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: And you could just use a Pivot Table.  If, when you create it, you select the option `Add to Data Model`, you will see a `Distinct Count` item in the Values settings for the Values.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I'm using O365, & actually I'm having some restriction to use pivot. So I'm using formula which didn't work & TomSharpe provided frequency formula didn't work, it shows count as 1.

Comment: OK, see my answer, and also my edit showing how to handle your more complex situation with no assigned Cluster's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula breaks around 50K rows. I don't know exactly why.

Much more reliable and faster to use Frequency for unique counts:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(Sheet1!B:B=A2,MATCH(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!A:A,0)),
IF(Sheet1!B:B=A2,MATCH(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!A:A,0)))>0))
```

entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

This is well-documented and there is an official Microsoft reference [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/count-unique-values-among-duplicates-8d9a69b3-b867-490e-82e0-a929fbc1e273)

[image]

If you have Office 365 you can use the unique function. This should work but I have only tested it on Google Sheets:

```
=COUNTA(unique(filter(sheet1!A:A,sheet1!B:B=a2)))
```

**EDIT**

For vm's that are not assigned try:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF((Sheet1!B:B="")*(Sheet1!A:A<>""),MATCH(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!A:A,0)),
IF((Sheet1!B:B="")*(Sheet1!A:A<>""),MATCH(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!A:A,0)))>0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I"m using O365, but the give Frequency formula doesn't work. Formula "=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(Sheet1!$B:$B=A2,MATCH(Sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)),IF(Sheet1!$B:$B=A2,MATCH(Sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)))>0))  it return it shows sum as 1

Comment: I've added more complicated situation where Cluster is not known, but we have VM's available. I've added image 3 for your reference. So how can we get the count of total VM's where Cluster isn't known?

Comment: Ah, I understand it better now that I can see how it looks on sheet 2. Will edit answer accordingly and look at the case where cluster isn't known.

Answer (score 1):

If you have O365 with the `FILTER` and `UNIQUE` functions, you can use the following:

*note that I inserted a Table for the data and named the table `vmTable`, but you can use regular addressing if you prefer*

```
D2: =UNIQUE(vmTable[Cluster])
E2: =ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(vmTable,vmTable[Cluster]=D2)))
```

- Select `E2` and copy/fill the formula down as far as required.

[image]

**edit**

For your more complicated situation where VM's are not assigned a cluster, you don't really have to do anything other than extend down the formula in Column E.  But if you want to avoid showing a `0` in Column D, then change the formula in D2:

```
=IF(UNIQUE(vmTable[Cluster])="","",UNIQUE(vmTable[Cluster]))
```

You could also use these formulas or a variation to provide a more understandable result table:

```
D2:  =IF(UNIQUE(vmTable[Cluster])="","None Assigned",UNIQUE(vmTable[Cluster]))
E2:  =ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(vmTable,vmTable[Cluster]= IF(D2="None Assigned","",D2))))
```

- Select `E2` and fill down

[image]